# Problems with css styles and js events with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, css, dom, cordova

The point is that my app looks cool in Firefox and Google Chrome.
But when I get the app compiled with PhoneGap, in my Android device it looks like "What happened with my CSS3 code and some JS events?". I can list the features not reflected in my PhoneGap app that are reflected in Firefox and Chrome browsers:

> - box-shadow
> - text-shadow
> - border-radius
> - flex and flex-*, justify-content, align-items (and flex-related stuff, in general)
> - transitions

And about JS, it is curious, because some events are fired, but others not.
Concretely, I use DOM manipulation via JS to deploy (manually-coded) dialogs (I mean, not alert, prompt or confirm functions), and when the dialog-button is pressed, the dialog itself disappears (also manually-coded). All OK in FF and Chrome, but with PhoneGap, the dialog is displayed but it is not removed when the dialog-button gets clicked.

I am not using any native functions, I am not using PhoneGap native features for JS, just pure web-client-side-JS. But anyway, I am using the event:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", myJSCode); //But it does not work...
```

Could anyone help me in this issue? I do not know what I can do, or where to find answers for this. Thank you a lot. If code is needed, just ask for it (it is a small tic-tac-toe game app, but I wanted to do it with PhoneGap... I still hope it was the right choice!)

Comment: I think it depends on what type of browser is on your android device, does it support those css3 features and so on.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense because of the things that are missing.
But if so, I could open the app with Firefox if I chose it as the default browser.
And I tried that just right now, and it looks the same... I will continue investigating...

Comment: Phonegap uses the native android browser so css and JS features may vary from device to device, you can use Modrnizr to detect those features from within the app. http://modernizr.com/

Comment: OK! I try and I tell you!!

Comment: After having a look to all these things, I am convinced that the problems were just a cross-browser issue. Thank you for naming Modernizr, it seemed to me time before an unnecessary library, but now I see the valuous work behind the scene. I will take a deeper look to that one. PD: All browsers should take standards seriously...